# Python как заменить спецсимвол \

Tags: python, строки, replace, обработка-ошибок, замена-текста

Столкнулся с необходимостью изменить путь к файлу с `C:\Users\1234\Desktop\spam` на `C:/Users/1234/Desktop/spam`, пытаясь использовать `replace()`  столкнулся с проблемой что питон считает `\` в строке `c = sms.replace("\","/")` за попытку перенести строку на новую и соответственно выдает ошибку,  как подобное можно обойти?

```
sms = ('C:\Users\1234\Desktop\sms')

c = sms.replace("\","/")

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы избежать проблем с экранированием символов, можно использовать сырые строки `(raw strings)` в `Python`, которые начинаются с буквы `r` перед открывающей кавычкой. В таких строках все символы, включая обратный слеш, считаются буквальными, то есть не используются для экранирования. А в функции  `replace()` вместо `\` используйте `\\`.

```
sms = r"C:\Users\1234\Desktop\sms"
c = sms.replace("\\", "/")
print(c)
```

Comment: В аргументе метода `replace` тоже можно использовать префикс `r`.